# How can I re-use data rows if I have too many vus?

Tags: javascript, k6

I've been reading various scenario-based options for using data (eg different row per iteration) and so on, but they all seem to imply / assume that data.length will equal the number of users / iterations.

What I'm wanting to do, is use a different row "where possible", but repeat data "when necessary. Eg, if I have 3 rows of data, and 10 users, users 1,4,7 and 10 will use row 1, users 2,5,8 will use row 2, and so on. I can't see any executor option I can put in a scenario that would cover this - unless I've misunderstood something. Instead, as a workaround I've come up with:

```
const csvData = new SharedArray('another data name', function () {
  // Load CSV file and parse it using Papa Parse
  return papaparse.parse(open('./unique_identifiers.csv'), { header: true }).data;
});

// *** SNIP

  const iteration = scenario.iterationInTest + 1
  const dataRows = csvData.length
  const rowForThisIteration = iteration%dataRows
```

then I can use `csvData[rowForThisIteration]`....

But can anyone suggest a better option - something built into K6 that I've missed?

Comment: What's wrong with `iteration%dataRows`?

Comment: Nothing "wrong" with it per se.... I think as much as anything I was wondering if I was re-inventing the wheel when K6 already has something more "built in" to support the same idea.

Comment: No, that's the way to do it.